# NumPy: how to filter out the first axes of multidimensional array according to some condition on the elements

Tags: numpy, filtering

Consider the follow ndarray `lm` -

```
In [135]: lm
Out[135]:
array([[[15,  7],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 0,  4]],

       [[ 8, 12],
        [ 6,  5],
        [17, 10]],

       [[16, 13],
        [30,  1],
        [14,  9]]])

In [136]: lm.shape
Out[136]: (3, 3, 2)
```

I want to filter out members of the first axes (`lm[0]`, `lm[1]`, ...) where at least one of the elements is greater than 20. Since `lm[2, 1, 0]` is the only element fulfills this condition, I would expect the following result -

```
array([[[15,  7],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 0,  4]],

       [[ 8, 12],
        [ 6,  5],
        [17, 10]]]
```

i.e `lm[2]` has at least one element > 20, so it is filtered out of the result set. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to do so with [`np.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) and [`np.any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) with `axis` arg  -

```
In [14]: lm[(lm<=20).all(axis=(1,2))]
Out[14]: 
array([[[15,  7],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 0,  4]],

       [[ 8, 12],
        [ 6,  5],
        [17, 10]]])

In [15]: lm[~(lm>20).any(axis=(1,2))]
Out[15]: 
array([[[15,  7],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 0,  4]],

       [[ 8, 12],
        [ 6,  5],
        [17, 10]]])
```

To make it generic for ndarrays to work along the last two axes, use `axis=(-2,-1)` instead.

Comment: thanks, I didn't realize the axis parameter could take a tuple

Comment: You could do `tuple(range(1, lm.ndim))`